# Add nodes to make local cluster Elasticsearch [7.8]

Tags: elasticsearch, cluster-computing, elastic-stack, elk, elasticsearch-7

I'm learning about Elastic Search (v7.8) so I made a local cluster to test it.
I made 3 virtual machines with Ubuntu 18, same amount of resources, in the same network with the IPs:

- 192.168.1.77
- 192.168.1.76
- 192.168.1.75

All correct individual installation, each respond to her API:

```
curl -XGET localhost:9200/?pretty
```

But when I tried to make a cluster editing `/etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml` each forms its own cluster of the same name with a single node.
Here my file: https://gist.github.com/RedxLus/f8eb561157c7f2b61fb4dfaa74fe8868

Here is the output of each node. Exactly the same.:

```
curl -XGET 192.168.1.77:9200/_cluster/health?pretty

{
  "cluster_name" : "luisiblog",
  "status" : "green",
  "timed_out" : false,
  "number_of_nodes" : 1,
  "number_of_data_nodes" : 1,
  "active_primary_shards" : 0,
  "active_shards" : 0,
  "relocating_shards" : 0,
  "initializing_shards" : 0,
  "unassigned_shards" : 0,
  "delayed_unassigned_shards" : 0,
  "number_of_pending_tasks" : 0,
  "number_of_in_flight_fetch" : 0,
  "task_max_waiting_in_queue_millis" : 0,
  "active_shards_percent_as_number" : 100.0
}
```

I don't know if it is a configuration error or if I have skipped any steps to add the nodes. I hope they help me. Thank you very much to all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing is that you are missing the `network.host` proper value which should be `0.0.0.0` to make sure this is visible on non-loopback address.

Can you try with below configs:

**#this is for node-1**

```
 cluster.name: elasticsearch
    node.name: node-1
    network.host: 0.0.0.0
    discovery.seed_hosts: ["192.168.1.77","192.168.1.76","192.168.1.75"]
    cluster.initial_master_nodes: ["192.168.1.77"]
    discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes : 1
    node.master: true
```

**#this is for node-2**

```
cluster.name: elasticsearch
node.name: node-2
network.host: 0.0.0.0
discovery.seed_hosts: ["192.168.1.77","192.168.1.76","192.168.1.75"]
cluster.initial_master_nodes: ["192.168.1.77"]
discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes : 1
node.master: false
```

**# this is for node-3**

```
cluster.name: elasticsearch
node.name: node-3
network.host: 0.0.0.0
discovery.seed_hosts: ["192.168.1.77","192.168.1.76","192.168.1.75"]
cluster.initial_master_nodes: ["192.168.1.77"]
discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes : 1
node.master: false
```

**Please not that I am making one dedicated master node, node-1 in this case**

Comment: It works! But only for one node, with what I have the master 192.168.1.77 and another. Checking the logs gives: failed to validate incoming join request from node.

Comment: @redxlus cool, but I didn't get what do you mean by only one node? and how you started the three nodes?

Comment: First stopped the service (`sudo service elasticsearch stop`). Delete the data (`sudo rm -rf /var/lib/elasticsearch/*`) and restart the service (`sudo service elasticsearch restart`). Now work all !! Thanks !