# Elasticsearch: setting up cluster with two nodes

Tags: elasticsearch, cluster-analysis

I've set two master nodes in my cluster but it only shows "elastic-master" not "elastic-slave".(second node is not shown).How can I resolve it?
I've already followed Elasticsearch documents but nothing changed!

My host file setting:

```
sudo nano /etc/hosts
192.168.143.30 elastic-master
192.168.143.23 elastic-slave
```

My config file:

```
# ---------------------------------- Cluster ------------------------------
cluster.name: elastic-a

# ------------------------------------ Node -------------------------------
node.name: elastic-master
node.master: true
node.data: true

# ---------------------------------- Network ------------------------------
network.host: 192.168.143.30
http.port: 9200
# --------------------------------- Discovery -----------------------------
discovery.seed_hosts: ["192.168.143.30","192.168.143.23"]
cluster.initial_master_nodes: ["elastic-slave", "elastic-master"]
```

My config file on second one:

```
# ---------------------------------- Cluster ------------------------------
cluster.name: elastic-a

# ------------------------------------ Node -------------------------------
node.name: elastic-slave
node.master: true
node.data: true

# ---------------------------------- Network ------------------------------
network.host: 192.168.143.23
http.port: 9200
# --------------------------------- Discovery -----------------------------
discovery.seed_hosts: ["192.168.143.30","192.168.143.23"]
cluster.initial_master_nodes: ["elastic-slave", "elastic-master"]
```

Comment: check and share the logs of two machine

Comment: Which version are you using?

Comment: @hamidbayat Which log do you want to see?

Comment: @leandrojmp CentOS 7 ,Elasticsearch 7.5 and Kibana 7.5

Comment: Your `discovery` settings are wrong, those changed in version 7, you need to `discovery.seed_hosts` and `cluster.initial_master_nodes` as explained in the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.5/modules-discovery-settings.html), also, this is your full `elasticsearcy.yml`? You are missing the `cluster.name` config, it should be the same on both.

Comment: @leandrojmp I just updated config file with "discovery.seed_hosts" and "cluster.initial_master_nodes" but it still doesn't workout.

Comment: Your second node config has the same `node.name`, it should be `elastic-slave`, change that and try again, and check the logs to find why they are not connecting. Also, with just only two nodes you should have only one master node eligible.

Answer (score 0):

"First stopped the service (sudo service elasticsearch stop). Delete the data (sudo rm -rf /var/lib/elasticsearch/*) and restart the service (sudo service elasticsearch restart). Now work all !!"
Found answer in here:
[Add nodes to make local cluster Elasticsearch [7.8]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62856133/add-nodes-to-make-local-cluster-elasticsearch-7-8)